# Recursive search error

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, recursion

running into a silly error and I just don't see it. I've been looking at this for a while and don't see what I'm missing. I am recursively searching an array for a specific target number but once I get up to element [7] it begins returning -1. Thanks for taking a look fellas/ladies!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] a = {1,25,2,6,4,3,23,30,32,14,11,8};
        Arrays.sort(a);
        int target = a[7];
        int first = a[0];
        int last = a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(" "+a[i]);
    }
        System.out.println("\n"+binarySearch(target,first,last,a));
    }
    public static int binarySearch(int target,int first, int last, int[] a)
    {
        int result;
        if(first>last)
            return -1;
        else
        {
            int mid = (first+last)/2;
            if(target == mid)
                result = mid;
            else if(target<a[mid])
                result = binarySearch(target,first,last-1,a);
            else
                result = binarySearch(target,mid+1,last,a);

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Specifically, when you calculate the mid, the mid you intend to calculate is the mid-index. So you can't use the values like so: `(first+last)/2`. You need indices. Right? Think think ... you will get there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In several places you fail to accurately distinguish between the value in an index of an array and the index itself.

This: `a[i]` gets the value at the ith element

This: `i` is simply an index, i

With that in mind, here is a fixed version of your code. See my comments in the code for some specific errors I fixed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] a = {1,25,2,6,4,3,23,30,32,14,11,8};
    Arrays.sort(a);
    int target = a[7];
//here you want the index of the first location to search, not the value in that index
//so you use 0 instead of a[0]
    int first = 0;
//the last element index is length-1, not length, since arrays are 0-based
    int last = a.length - 1;     
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(" "+a[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n"+binarySearch(target,first,last,a));
}

public static int binarySearch(int target,int first, int last, int[] a)
{
    int result;
    if(first>last)
        return -1;
    else
    {
        int mid = (first+last)/2;
//here you need to check if the target is equal to the value at the index mid
//before you were checking if the target was equal to the index, which was never true
        if(target == a[mid])
//you want to return the value at the target, not the index of the target
//so use a[mid] not mid
            result = a[mid];
        else if(target<a[mid])
//here you want to search from first to mid-1
//before you were searching from first to last-1, which is not correct binary search
            result = binarySearch(target,first,mid - 1,a);
        else
            result = binarySearch(target,mid + 1,last,a);

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried this..this does not work it just gives me the target the target as an int not as a the index of the target

Comment: I mean I had this thought minutes before you answered but still not correct.

Comment: @JaredWaxler I am running it and it returns 7, which is the index of the target. Please explain what it outputs for you if you are saying that it outputs something different.

Comment: It is suppose to return the index of what exists at a[7] not 7.

Comment: which is the number 14 after the sort

Comment: @JaredWaxler no problem. I will edit the code to change that, but it is a very easy fix: simply change `result=mid` to `result=a[mid]. Please remember to upvote and accept if this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the code comments, I know I was mixing up my indices with elements. I began going down a rabbit hole lol. Thank you. I was close.

Comment: @JaredWaxler you were definitely almost there. happy to help!